# UPDATE vs UPDATE WHERE

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have a table with many rows, where I periodically want to set one column to `0` using a cron.

What is faster / less memory consuming, doing an `UPDATE` on all rows (ie. no `WHERE` clause) or doing an `UPDATE` only `WHERE mycolumn != 0`?

Comment: How about trying both and comparing the results ?

Comment: might depend on index on `mycolumn`

Comment: Do you have any triggers on UPDATE for this table?

Comment: No, no triggers, and no index.

Comment: @EduardLuca if you don't use `WHERE` one day you will make the biggest mistake of your life

Comment: @meda why do you say that? :)

Comment: @EduardLuca I guess meda is concerned with some possible error in interactive mode (i'm also wary when doing queries ad-hoc), but for a cron job, this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed in comments on the original post, it depends on several things (index, database engine, type of storage media, available cache memory, etc.).

We *could* make an educated guess that:

a) We should always have a full-table scan unless we have an index on the column (and I'd not recommend one just for the sake of this query, as you will penalize down your online writes to benefit an offline process);

b) The "cost" for checking the values is highly amortized by the savings of not writing unchanged records (unless the database implicitly does so, which may or may not happen) *if* the majority of records will be zeroes.

but assumptions start to pile up, so I'd rather **measure** instead. To play a bit, I've:

- Created a test table with a "status" numeric column
- Filled it with a few million records (e.g., using a script like the one in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17268740/64635)
- Set it up with different values, then tried to `UPDATE` the column to 0, with and without the `WHERE`.

My results (which *may* differ from yours) were that the WHERE query was way faster *if* there were indeed few non-zero records. E.g., after setting up the table with either of

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = 1;                /* All values non-zero (1) */
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = FLOOR(RAND()*10); /* ~90% values non-zero */
```

both `WHERE` and non-`WHERE` updates to 0 were slow (and no noticeable difference between them, implying "a" above is true), whereas after any of

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = 0;                      /* All values zero */
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = IF(id % 500 = 0, 1, 0); /* 99.8% values zero */
```

the `UPDATE` with `WHERE` was insanely faster (as implied by "b").

I'd recommend trying these tests (and even others, including the index if you really wish) on your setup (e.g., creating a separate table and running tests like these) and consider your data set (measure/estimate the % of records that will be non-zero when your cron job runs). Keep in mind you likely want to optimize for cost/availability (including *your* time as a cost) instead of finding the absolutely most performant solution in the universe (which is likely not cost-effective), and you will surely find the best solution. Good luck!