# Time complexity: UPDATE ... WHERE vs UPDATE ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am having a database table `DuplicatesRemoved` with possibly large number of records. I execute certain operations to remove duplicates of users in my application, and every time I remove the duplicates, I keep a track of the duplicate `UserID`'s by storing them in this table `DuplicatesRemoved`.

This table contains a bit field `HistoryRecord`. I need to update this field at the end of every "RemoveDuplicates" operation.

I do NOT have any indexes on `DuplicatesRemoved`.

I am wondering which of these would be better?

**1.**

```
UPDATE DuplicatesRemoved SET HistoryRecord=1 WHERE HistoryRecord<>1
```

OR

**2.**

```
UPDATE DuplicatesRemoved SET HistoryRecord=1
```

Will Query #1 take less time than Query #2?

I have referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839633/update-vs-update-where) but still am not sure about which one would be better for me.

Comment: Depends on the database. For example Mysql treats them the same - if there's no actual change in the data, no update is recorded. Which DB are you using.

Comment: @Bohemian I am using SQL Server

Comment: What proportion of the records are <>1 ? Are these records a known value like for example 0?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid As mentioned in the issue description, it is a BIT field DEFAULT to 0. Also, majority of records are <>1. As and how the database increases, the proportion of records <>1 will keep reducing.

Answer (score 1):

In the first option:

```
UPDATE DuplicatesRemoved SET HistoryRecord=1 WHERE HistoryRecord<>1
```

You have to find those records and **update only those**.

In the second option:

```
UPDATE DuplicatesRemoved SET HistoryRecord=1
```

**You have to update the entire table.**

So first option will be better assuming you find the records quickly, and also minimizes the number of locks acquired during the time of the update, and the total size of the transaction that the engine writes to the log file (i.e the records that we need to be able to rollback).

Showing the execution plan will help in this decision.

Comment: Query with WHERE shows these statistics:
Table Update Cost: 75%
Table Scan Cost: 25%


Query for update all shows:
Table Update Cost: 81%
Table Scan Cost: 19%

Comment: Assuming the source table is very big, this operation can crash your database or have terrible performance.

Answer (score 0):

In databases, you measure the number of disk accesses to evaluate the complexity of a query, since the time to read something from the external memory is order of magnitute greater than the time to perform few operations in main memory.

The two queries, if no index is present, have the same number of disk accesses, since both require the complete scan of the relation.