# Is there a way to enrich JSON field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json

Let's take a simple schema with two tables, one that describes an simple entity *item* (id, name)

```
id  |   name
------------
1   |   foo
2   |   bar
```

and another, lets call it *collection*, that references to an *item*, but inside a JSON Object in something like

```
{
    items: [
        {
            id: 1,
            quantity: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm looking for a way to eventually enrich this field (kind of like *populate* in Mongo) in the *collection* with the *item* element referenced, to retrieve something like

```
{
    ...
    items: [
        {
            item: {
                id: 1,
                name: foo
            },
            quantity: 2
        }
    ]
    ...
}
```

If you have a solution with PostgreSQL, I take it as well.

Comment: Have you already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766282/fill-database-tables-with-a-large-amount-of-test-data)?

Comment: You should read about the [Inner-platform Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your requirement is to convert an Input JSON data into MySQL table so that you can work with JSON but leverage the power of SQL.

Mysql8 recently released [JSONTABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) function. By using this function, you can store your JSON in the table directly and then query it like any other SQL query.

It should serve your immediate case, but this means that your table schema will have a JSON column instead of traditional MySQL columns. You will need to check if it serves your purpose.

[This](https://mysqlserverteam.com/json_table-the-best-of-both-worlds/) is a good tutorial for the same.

Comment: This should give me the tools to achieve what I'm looking for, thanks!